# Reactjs - upgrade to version 17.0.0

Tags: reactjs, events, react-dom

I have just upgraded my app from `reactjs` 16.14.0 to 17.0.0 but I met this issue:

When I click a button or any actions it is not catching an event to go to my function.

I have read `reactjs` docs, which say: move all event listeners from `Document` to `document.getElementById('root')`. Maybe my issue is related to this?

```js
    const search = () => {
        dispatch(loadAccounts(filterName));
    };

    const onChangeAccountId = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        setFilterName(e.target.value);
    };

    const onKeyPressEnter = (e: any) => e.key === 'Enter' && search();

    return (
        <div className='search-panel'>
            <Select options={options} onChange={onChangeClassCode} className='select fieldset' value={options[0]}/>
            <input className='fieldset filter-input' type='text' name='updateBy' value={filterName} onChange={onChangeAccountId} onKeyPress={onKeyPressEnter}/>
            <Button className='fieldset' onClick={search}>SEARCH</Button>
            <Button className='add-profile' onClick={search}>ADD CORPORATE PROFILE</Button>
        </div>
    );
```

Comment: i am upgrade . with commands `yarn upgrade react@latest react-dom@latest` and last command `yarn`.and not problem

Comment: I also upgrade with yarn but I also meet this issue.

Comment: Order is important . `yarn upgrade react@latest react-dom@latest` and `yarn`.and see `package.json` is changed?

Comment: yes. Changed, and run success, but don't recive any event when clicking an action. I used webpack 4.4.2

Comment: if add sample code in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) or github for debugging is great.

Comment: my project: https://github.com/nhutlbuit/corporate-account-ui

Comment: I could . I am very happy.I updated a series of packages how to inform?Do I comite in GitHub?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223704/discussion-between-a-r-seif-and-nhutle).

Comment: Amazing. I have just updated successfully. I will review version of packages above. Thanks so much!

Comment: I have reviewed all of dependences as @A.R.SEIFsaid. Here is the problem: "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0". I gone up to version 4.5.0 to solve it.